# How to use I18n in a Rails' helper via a frozen class string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, ruby-on-rails-5.2, load-path

My Helper..

```
module WatableHelper

  # binding.pry

  ANALYTICS_MEMBERS_FORMAT_COLS = {
    email:  {
      index:    1,
      type:     'string',
      friendly: I18n.t('system_roles.email'),
      unique:   true
    },
    name:   {
      index:    2,
      type:     'string',
      friendly: I18n.t('admin_courses.th.name'),
      filter:   ''
    },
    status: {
      index:    3,
      type:     'string',
      friendly: I18n.t('admin_courses.th.status'),
      filter:   false
    }
  }.freeze
```

When this class is loaded it will return :

`translation missing: en.system_roles.email`

The reason being is that if I run `I18n.load_path`, I can see that none of my locales have been loaded yet. I'm guessing this is because Rails will boot the Rails helpers before the locales, and after that string gets set, it gets frozen as `translation missing`.

If I run `reload!` in my console, this class will load as expected, and my locales are then located within the load path.

Anyone have any idea what the proper way to load those I18n translations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe can you try to require your locale, in this way it will loaded before:

`require_relative 'your_path/until/your_locale`

Comment: Definitely an honest response. I think for now I'm going with just baking these in as private methods instead of class constants.